# AWS step scaling adding more tasks than configured

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I am trying to scale up the number of ECS tasks by adding a step scaling policy . The step scaling policy is triggered on the queue parameter ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible when it crosses a threshold .

The scaling policy is defined as below

```
scale-up-task-on-queue: ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible > 10
Policy type: Step scaling
For alarm: some-alarm-name
Take the action:
Add 2 tasks when 10 < ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible < 15
Add 2 tasks when 15 <= ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible < 20
Add 2 tasks when 20 <= ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible
```

I am starting with 1 task , and i am posting approximately 60 -70 messages in the queue to trigger the alarm . I am ideally expecting it to have 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 7  tasks count , but i am seeing that the task count is going up to  15-16 .  What could be happening ?

Comment: Have you set `Maximum number of tasks` to 7 if you don't want more?

Comment: @Marcin That did come to my mind , but  we have one more policy to scale on CPU .So didnt want to restrict it to 7. As a last resort will probably set  to a max of 10-11.

Comment: The step policy will keep firing as along as conditions are satisfied. You can extend cooldown period, or make alarm period longer. This way you can give the current tasks some time to reduce the number of messages from the queue.

Comment: @Marcin that makes sense . I am just trying `ExactCapacity` vs `ChangeInCapacity` to see if it better fits the need . Will post back here after trying.

Comment: Let me know how it will go. Curious to see how the issue can be resoloved.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

1. Its not going to trigger all 3 of the steps and add 6.  It will pick a single step based on the metric value.  So if the metric value is 60, it will do +2 (since that's the adjustment set for "20 <=".  You should probably set the first step as +2, the second as +4, and the 3rd as +6 if that's the behavior you want
2. As @Marcin mentioned in the comments, the alarm will continue to trigger the scaling policy every minute that it stays in the alarm state.  So as soon as the cooldown ends, the policy will continue to increase the task count until either the alarm isn't in the alarm state anymore, or the Max size is reached.  Increasing the cooldown or making sure your tasks are setting the SQS messages to not visible when the messages are removed from the queue would help with this.  The one issue I can think of with this is that the cooldown would apply to the whole ECS service, so it would also potentially prevent the CPU scaling policy from adding tasks.

Setting the metric values further apart might help.  That way if the first step gets triggered, and you have it at +1, it'll add 1 task.  Then if more messages come in right after and it goes up to the second step, which is configured for +2, it'll only add 1 more tasks (since there would still be 1 in cooldown).
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/application-auto-scaling-step-scaling-policies.html